# Printing integer returns *0x0

Tags: c

I'm learning C and trying to understand the printf function better.

When I print:

```
printf("%d", 6 << 1);
```

it returns `120x0` instead of the expected `12`. Why is that? I'm using gcc compiler.

Comment: You sure? http://ideone.com/0eV8WZ

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show your entire code!

Comment: yes thats how I found out my results were abnormal

Comment: I think that this printf prints 12, while some subsequent printf (or other output fucntion) prints 0x0

Comment: To check modify your code as follows:

Comment: Is this the only statement in your code?

Comment: Only statement in function

Comment: @RustyShackleford Show your whole code

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Ok, in other words. You need to make a reproducible example to show, because I showed you, the code is OK.

Comment: modify your code as follows: printf("%d\n", 6<<1);
and check if carriage return is printed

Comment: Is this your only `printf`? Add a newline at the end and you will see that this prints 12.

Comment: `0x0` might the return value of the `main()` i.e. the exit code.

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
printf("%d", 6 << 1);
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", 6 << 1);
```

and try to always add a newline character to distinguish the printed text from other output, unless you need to print things next to each other.

You should now see

```
12
0x00
```

Answer (score 2):

most likely you're code is working properly printing `12` and later you print `0x0` somewhere.